# Neo4j - return results from match results starting from specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets say i have nodes that are connected in FRIEND relationship.
I want to query 2 of them each time, so i use SKIP and LIMIT to maintain this.

However, if someone adds a FRIEND in between calls, this messes up my results (since suddenly the 'whole list' is pushed 1 index forward).

For example, lets say i had this list of friends (ordered by some parameter):

A B C D

I query the first time, so i get A B (skipped 0 and limited 2).
Then someone adds a friend named E, list is now E A B C D.
now the second query will return B C (skipped 2 and limited 2). Notice B returned twice because the skipping method is not aware of the changes that the DB had.

Is there a way to return 2 each time starting considering the previous query? For example, if i knew that B was last returned from the query, i could provide it to the query and it would query the 2 NEXT, getting C D (Which is correct) instead of B C.

I tried finding a solution and i read about START and indexes but i am not sure how to do this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You could store a timestamp when the `FRIEND` relationship was created and order by that property.

When the `FRIEND` relationship is created, add a timestamp property:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: "Bob"}), (b:Person {name: "Mike"})
CREATE (a)-[r:FRIEND]->(b)
SET r.created = timestamp()
```

Then when you are paginating through friends two at a time you can order by the `created` property:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: "Bob"})-[r:FRIEND]->(friends)
RETURN friends SKIP {page_number_times_page_size} LIMIT {page_size} 
ORDER BY r.created
```

You can parameterize this query with the page size (the number of friends to return) and the number of friends to skip based on which page you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However i think this doesnt solve the problem - If i add a new friend, it still pushes the already existing ones forward (to be re-queried by the skip).

I need a way to start the querying FROM a specific timestamp. that would be the complete solution :) is that possible? (lets say i first queried someone at timestamp X, then even if timestamp Y is newer, i still start querying from X and the skip would be correct).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if It's not exactly answer to you question. On my previous project I had experience of modifying big data. It wasn't possible to modify everything with one query so I needed to split it in batches. First I started with skip limit. But for some reason in some cases it worked unpredictable (not modified all the data). And when I become tired of finding the reason I changed my approach. I used Java for querying database. So I get all the ids that I needed to modify in first query. And after this I run through stored ids.